# Editing raster band metadata using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, editing, metadata

How does one manually change STATISTIC_MIN/STATISTIC_MAX metadata within a raster band using gdal?

I want to preserve the color scale but ensure that the STATISTIC values are set as needed.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Use `gdal_edit.py -unsetstats your_raster_file` arg to remove existing stats, then `gdalinfo -stats your_raster_file` to recalculate them.

- https://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html
- https://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html